# DIfferent PCA results between Sklearn and Tensorflow projector

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, pca

I've a certain data and when I use the Tensorflor projector with default settings, I get the following visual:

[image]

However, when I use plotly and sklearn to plot the same, I get this:

[image]

The code I have used for PCA is:

```
  pca_2d = PCA(n_components=2)
  PCs_2d = pd.DataFrame(pca_2d.fit_transform(x))
  PCs_2d.columns = ["PC1_2d", "PC2_2d"]
```

Note that my dataset is just a bunch of binary variables. Therefore, I don't believe normalisation is a factor.

Why would the TF Projector plot look so much better than mine on the exact same data ?

Comment: Actually they are both same. The only difference is `tensorflow` enables you to look from above, where `sklearn` displays in a sideview.

Comment: I don't think that is the case. I tried the 3D plot in both tensorflow and sklearn, and the graphs were drastically different.